# WPF: Applying multiple data templates?

Tags: wpf, xaml, datatemplate

Let's say I am displaying a data component, such as TreeView.

Let's say it is bound to a tree structure, of base type TreeViewItem.

```
TreeViewItem
    TreeViewItem
    TreeViewItem
        TreeViewItem
```

and so on.

But some of those items are more specific implementations of TreeViewItem such as AnimalTreeViewItem and even more granular ZebraTreeViewItem

```
TreeViewItem
    AnimalTreeViewItem
        ZebraTreeViewItem
    PlantTreeViewItem
```

Now, let's say i want these items to be rendered in a similar fashion, but there would be slight differences in rendering depending on underlying type.

One way i've gotten this to work, is using DataTemplate.

Problem is that i have to create a separate template for each type, with 100% of contents defined in the same way (minus small difference in layout / color etc)

Is there  a way to define data templates, that share most of their contents together? meaning, w/out having to create 2 templates, that are almost identical in their markup, just to change the background color of some textbox etc..

Answer (score 1):

You might be interested in the solution shown in [this article](http://www.thomaslevesque.com/2011/10/01/wpf-creating-parameterized-styles-with-attached-properties/). It works fine if the differences between are minor, e.g. a different color for some element, but it can also handle more complex scenarios through the use of triggers.

Comment: +1 for the inheritance value in attached properties.Wasn't aware of it till now.

Answer (score 0):

The answer to this question is DataTriggers

```
<DataTemplate x:Key="myTaskTemplate">
  ...
<DataTemplate.Triggers>
  <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding Path=TaskType}">
    <DataTrigger.Value>
      <local:TaskType>Home</local:TaskType>
    </DataTrigger.Value>
    <Setter TargetName="border" Property="BorderBrush" Value="Yellow"/>
  </DataTrigger>
</DataTemplate.Triggers>
  ...
</DataTemplate>
```

This data template will only be 'triggered' when the TaskType is Home.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms742521.aspx#adding_more_to_datatemplate